# Changing canPlaceOn/canDestroy display names of blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm building a resource pack for a map, to implement a common workaround for `canDestroy` and `canPlaceOn` not supporting block metadata (retexturing completely different blocks to look like the block that's supposed to be usable). I already got in all the textures and also already modified the blocks' names to be what they look like (in the `en_US.lang`). The one thing I'm currently unable to figure out is how to change the block names displayed in the `canDestroy`/`canPlaceOn` lore. So that, for example, instead of "Can be placed on: Stained Clay" it says "Can be placed on: Chiseled Red Sandstone". I cannot find any information on that anywhere.

Comment: Related but not duplicate: [How can I make an item display fake CanPlaceOn/CanDestroy data?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372237/how-can-i-make-an-item-display-fake-canplaceon-candestroy-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the `en-US.lang` has "general" entries for blocks (e.g. `tile.clayHardenedStained.name` in addition to `tile.clayHardenedStained.black.name`, `tile.clayHardenedStained.red.name` etc.). Not sure if those are the right ones, but chances seem good they are. (Update: As of version 1.8, those are indeed the correct fields.)